# defining a custom logger in grails 3 using logback

Tags: logback, grails-3.0

I want to define a different logger from the default to log things in a different file. I've try to define a custom logger. The file is created but grails never logs anything.

```
appender("APPENDER", FileAppender) {
file = "logs/info.log"
append = true
encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%level - %msg%n"
    }
}
logger("logger", INFO, ['APPENDER'], false)
```

Then in a controller I want to call it using: *log.info "something"* but nothing is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add: import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO
Where: conf/logback.groovy file

Thanks "nayan kakati" I've figured out earlier!

Answer (score 0):

This contains daily rolling policy and max size of the log file. The catch is /var/logs should have a write access.

```
def currentDay = timestamp("yyyyMMdd")
    appender(FILE, RollingFileAppender) {
        file = "/var/logs/info_${currentDay}.log"
        rollingPolicy(FixedWindowRollingPolicy) {
            fileNamePattern = "/var/logs/info_${currentDay}.%i.log"
            minIndex = 1
            maxIndex = 9
        }
        triggeringPolicy(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy) {
            maxFileSize = "50MB"
        }
        encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
            pattern = "%level %date %logger - %msg%n"
        }
        append = true
    }
```

**Note:** your user should have a write access to /var/logs/

Comment: I can log only ERROR messages, prehaps the problem is that I can't enable other type of logging service. Do you know how to enable INFO logger?

Comment: 1. add this line at the end->>>  root(INFO, [FILE])
2. For console printing add this line->>  logger("console", INFO, [STDOUT], false)

Comment: @Tincho include->>> import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO